# Что делает файл show.php?

Tags: php, ajax

У меня вопрос по одной статье: itmemo.ru/2012/02/ajax-i-php-rabota-s-bazoy-dannyih
Подскажите пожалуйста, что происходит в файле show.php? Дело в том, что и в show.php пробуют вывести данные из бд и в index.php Отсюда не понимание, что делает каждый из файлов...
У меня была уверенность в том, что в index.php должно было быть подключение ajax(show.php), однако никакого include в index.php почему-то нет. Прошу помочь разобраться до конца, как работает ajax

Answer (score 2):

Примерчик вы конечно выбрали очень невысокого качества. Но давайте разбираться.

Для начала код show.php:

```php
<?php
include "auth.php"; //Подключаем БД
//делаем запрос на товары этой категории
$query = "select * from allcat where Id_parent=".$_REQUEST['idcat']."";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// выводим товары полученные по запросу
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
print $row['Name']."<br>";
}
?>
```

1. Подключаем БД. Файл в котором создаётся подключение к базе назван auth.php, -- неудачное название (лучше было бы `db.php`). Тут всё понятно? [include](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php), [функции для работы с MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.mysql.php) (обратите внимание что "этот модуль устарел с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалён в версии 7.0.0.").
2. Делаем запрос на товары этой категории. Снова всё просто -- делаем запрос в базу, получаем результат и выводим имена товаров через `<br>`. Тут автор снова подложил вам свинью и допустил [SQL-инъекцию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Если забить на все косяки этого кода, то в index.php формируется HTML-страничка с js-кодом запроса.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#idcat').change(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "show.php",
data: "idcat="+$("#idcat").val(),
success: function(html){
$("#content").html(html);
}
});
return false;
});

});
```

Этот код использует [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (в настоящее время использование jQuery считается плохим тоном) и будет работать только, если вы подключите библиотеку на эту страницу. Суть jQuery-кода в том, что он запрашивает `show.php` и тот HTML (имена товаров через `<br>`) добавляет на страницу.

Итого:

1. В show.php просто выводится список товаров указанной категории через `<br>`. Можете запросить `show.php` напрямую и увидите этот список.
2. Не испоьзуйте этот пример для своего кода. Пример содержит плохой код и критические уязвимости.

Чтобы разобраться с PHP и AJAX разберитесь с ними отдельно. По AJAX хороший учебник на [javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch) и [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за разъяснения и за ссылки. Вы случайно не знаете материал, который объяснял подобную тему (я про динамический вывод из базы данных) Где ajax объяснялся с php, где вот так объяснялась логика взаимодействия файлов?